# Type 'String' does not conform to protocol 'NSCopying' error when getting object from NSDictionary

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting an error when trying to extract an object from a NSDictionary in Swift:

> Type 'String' does not conform to protocol 'NSCopying'

I tried to cast the key from String to NSString but I does not solve the issue. Can anyone shed some light? Here is the code:

```
var excerciseCategoryDictionary = object as NSDictionary

let category = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(NSStringFromClass(ExcerciseCategory.self),
                            inManagedObjectContext: AppDelegate.sharedInstance().managedObjectContext) as ExcerciseCategory

category.name = excerciseCategoryDictionary["name"]
```

The error occurs on the last line.

[image]

Comment: Dear downvoter, cab you please tell me why `-1`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Swift automatically converts `NSDictionary` as `Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>`. If you know that a value stored in a `NSDictionary` is a string, then you have to cast to `String`.

The problem in your case is about the value, not the key, so you just have to cast as follows:

```
category.name = excerciseCategoryDictionary["name"] as String
```

or

```
category.name = excerciseCategoryDictionary["name"] as String?
```

depending from what's the actual type of the object you are assigning the value